# eclipse always starts with workspace in root

Tags: eclipse, virtualbox, workspace, ubuntu-14.04

This was question was asked before, but none of the answers works for me. I am running Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 14.04 in a vb 4.3.10. At each startup of eclipse it wants to put the workspace into root. Even when I override that and tell it to use the new workspace as default it forgets about it until the next opening. Also, changing workspaces within eclipse does not change anything: at next startup it wants to put the workspace again into root.
What to do?????

Answer (score 1):

Try to download a new version of eclipse, or remove all the old configurations. To remove the old configurations,

1. Go to eclipse folder, where eclipse is kept
2. Remove configuration/.settings from there

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions issue to me. Check that the file `configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` is writable by you; it has a `RECENT_WORKSPACES` key that specifies the recently used workspaces.